# can't install some packages with conda install or pip install

Tags: python, csv, pip, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda3 in my computer and created a virtualenv named Python27 with python version 2.7, I want to install several packages in my virtualenv, but conda install or pip install works for some packages and not for others, for example, I was not able to install csv, a package to manage comma separated values documents, this is the output I get using conda install:

```
$ conda install csv
Fetching package metadata .........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - csv

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

and using pip install:

```
$ pip install csv
Collecting csv
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for csv
```

How do I install the package csv in my virtualenv or any other package I was not able to install this way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install csv, because it is already included in your python installation.

Just go

```
import csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard library module: [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). It should be available without installation.

Just to make sure I tested it with a clean environment.

```
$ conda create -n test python   # new environment without any additional packages
$ activate test                 # go to that environment
$ python                        # start the python interpreter
>>> import csv                  # importing it works!
```